# What are the pros and cons of the Microsoft Surface Pro 4 for video editing?

Tags: hardware, recommendation

I'm in the market for a new computer. I really, *really* want mobility. I have been considering the newest Microsoft Surface Pro 4. I would get the model with the highest ram and processing specs. From reading the specs, it seems to me that it would be plenty powerful enough to do standard video editing (1080p or less), and with the dock, probably recording over USB3 just fine as well. Combined with external monitors, it seems I would have the best of both worlds (mobile and powerful).

But I might be wrong. What are the pros and cons that I may not be seeing?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, mobility would be your biggest pro by far. With the Surface Pro with highest specs (as you mentioned), you'll get a very competitive machine. The biggest thing you'll be missing (from my perspective) is a dedicated graphics card. You can probably still pull off multiple monitors, but it's not going to be pushing it for sure. The [Surface Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0163GS05Q) actually does have a dedicated GPU, and could combine that mobility with a powerful graphics card (it does come at quite a bit extra cost, though).

The best thing I've found with my Surface (a Surface Pro 3, admittedly, but still in the same family) is that I can connect a mouse and external keyboard via Bluetooth (was never a fan of the Type Cover) and still have my USB port free.